# jQuery Ajax: Parse Error Getting Result to Alert Box

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a very simple ajax call to my handler from jquery which is failing to retrive data and it gives me `parsererror` when i try to show the result in alert box.

## ASP.NET Handler code:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
          string json = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Write(json);
    }
```

## Jquery

```
$('.submit').on("click",function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data1 = { "hi": "hello" };
            alert(data1.hi);
            $.ajax({
                  url: "/charity-challenge/CompetitionHelper.ashx",
                  data: data1,
                  dataType: 'json',
                  type: 'POST',
                  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                  success: function (data) {
                         alert("response = " + data);
                  },
                  error: function (data, status) {
                         alert("FAILED:" + status);
                  }
            });
      });
```

Note: I can see the response coming fine in chrome while debugging. BUT somehow when i try to show it in alert box it gives me parsererror.

Also, I want to assign the json data in handler. i dont have any clue how to do that.

i have a sample calss like this in handler. how to loop through the json data and assign values to this variables so i can work on those.

```
public class userData
      {
            public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
            public string EntryId { get; set; }
      }
```

## Found the work around to this.

i added a complete callback and now its showing the result in alertbox. i dont know why it is not working without it BUT if someone knows please post the answer.

here is the complete call back.

```
complete: function(xhr, status) {
            if (status === 'error' || !xhr.responseText) {
                alert("Error");
            }
            else {
                var data = xhr.responseText;
                alert(data);
                //...
            }
        }
```

Comment: so in chrome, you see `response = [json object]`? FYI, replace alert with console.log and look in console to see how data really loooks on return. if it's a json object, the problem maybe you trying to send an object as string to alert

Comment: Yes, i can see the entire json object like this. "hi=hello" in response tab of chrome XHR debugger...

Comment: tried with console.log. its still showing me parsererror.

Comment: i'm still confused, so you're somehow getting a ParseError AFTER expected return on success callback? That just doesn't make since?

Comment: this is what i also dont understand... getting back the result but then how come error callback is called...

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with your request payload being sent by the ajax call as hi=hello

As a test, try this (requires Newtonsoft.Json nuget):

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
 {
    //string json = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { hi = "hello" }));
 }
```

So I guess you have to parse your input stream e generate the json correctly.

You could also fix this in the client side, by calling using JSON.stringify(data1) in your data parameter in the ajax call.